# What does Asp.net 5 and Asp.net core 5 options under References in Visual studio 2015 mean?

Tags: asp.net-core

When i tried to add reference in Visual studio 2015, i got confused seeing this 2 options under references "Asp.net5 and Asp.net core 5" .

Could any one please throw some light about that.

Comment: May be core is the cloud deployment model for asp.net with minimal set of functions and the other being a full blown version

Comment: I don't think its because of cloud deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET 5 is now a single framework that runs on top of either .NET Core 5 runtime (Core-CLR) or the .NET Framework runtime (CLR).

ASP.NET 5 is the first workload that has adopted .NET Core. ASP.NET 5 runs on both the .NET Framework and .NET Core. A key value of ASP.NET 5 is that it can run on multiple versions of .NET Core 5 on the same machine. Website A and website B can run on two different versions of .NET Core on the same machine, or they can use the same version.

It’s up to you. Due to its smaller footprint, there are also some performance benefits that are specific to .NET Core, however, most of the ASP.NET 5 performance benefits apply to both the .NET Framework and .NET Core.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you add a nuget package to your project, it will be applicable to one or more frameworks.  You add these packages in your project.json file in the 'dependencies' section.

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity": "3.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-*"
}
```

The two main frameworks you will see are 'aspnet50' and 'aspcore50'.  You will specify which framework(s) you would like to target in your project.json file.

```
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {
        "frameworkAssemblies": {
        },
        "dependencies": {
        }
    },
    "aspnetcore50": { }
}
```

In that section, you can also specify dependencies that you only want included for a specific framework.  Inside your code, you will want to protect framework specific code.

```
#ifdef aspnet50
    /* code targeting dependencies only available for aspnet50 */
#endif
```

The nodes you see under the 'References' node will visualize which packages are being included for which framework.  The framework your application is running against will be configured in the application host.